# Solspace Calendar: showing non-ongoing events and only ongoing

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar, calendar-events

I need to show a list of event per one day, lets say Today, that are only today and not repeating, and after that list I need to show events that are ongoing. I'm already filtering events per one day and that works but no sure how to filter just one day events (that don't repeat, even they are from today till tomorrow for example) and after events that are ongoing that repeat weekly/monthly etc..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `{exp:calendar:cal}` to zoom in on "today", and filter out recurring events using `{if event_recurs}...{/if}`. Eg.:

```
{exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="today" date_range_end="today" pad_short_weeks="n"}
    {events}
        {if event_recurs}
        {if:else}
            [{event_id}] {event_title}<br /> /* ...and other event data */
        {/if}
    {/events}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```